# File permissions for CodeIgniter on Ubuntu web server

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu, file-permissions

I have a CodeIgniter app running in production on Apache 2.2 with PHP 5.3 on Ubuntu 11.10. I am also running PHP5-APC, if that matters. So the app runs as `www-data:www-data` per the default Apache2 install.

I am trying to figure out what to set my file permission to. Many threads on SO seem to prefer `755` for directories and `644` for files. There is one directory that must allow files to be uploaded to it.

Currently my deployment script does something like this:

- wipe old site
- copy new site over
- `chmod -R 000` on the new site
- `chmod` all directories to `500`
- `chmod` all files to `400`
- `chmod 700` on the upload directory

Everything seems to work fine. I can upload files and so on.. so, I don't understand why people suggest `644` for files - I have a config file that has passwords and API keys - why would I want 'others' to have read-access to it?

What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, mainly the `644` permission is meant for when you have `/var/www/site1.com` with different user and group set then `www-data`, because then the `644` would allow other groups and users to **read** from that file, but will allow to **read** and **write** the owner of the file.

As by default the user that uploads files and runs apache's processes is `www-data` then I honestly think that if it works for you and you have no issues, it's great because means a little more security.

### Update

Just a small security issue, is that `www-data` has become a very common user and group for `http` services to run their processes. I would much recommend that each site/app have their own user and group.

Answer (score 2):

*44 and *55 just means that the file/folder is readable by others.

This would be good if say, you uploaded files to the web server but they for some reason were owned by someone else (say your own login account), then apache could still read them and it'd be "no fuss". Or if you needed multiple groups to be able to access the files.

If you know you are uploading the files as the apache user, and apache (or whichever programs run under www-data) are all you need to be able to read/write the files, then *00 is completely fine. It can even be argued that it's a little more secure.

For people who don't know what they're doing on the linux command line, 644 and 755 are about the right mix between "convenient" and "safe" (completely debatable, though), so they are what is recommended for a quick fix.

Answer (score 2):

When doing shared hosting, you have user accounts that upload php files via FTP. So, when user "joe" uploads his .php file, it is owned by "joe" and when Apache needs to read it to execute the script, it cannot. Users are usually in "users" group, so even giving privilege to the group would not be enough. That's why you need to give privilege to everyone, so that user "www-data" can read the file uploaded by "joe".

If you run your own server, than of course, you have full control and none of this matters.